# Understanding dielectric readings - Water vs Apple Sauce (for example)

Tags: dielectric

I thought asking this question here might be the easiest way to get an answer. I'm not looking for an exact answer, just an explanation of why this is the case.

I used a Chirp! sensor connected to an Arduino Uno. The reading in AIR was 209, at 22 degrees C. In tap water the reading was 488 at 19 degrees C. In Apple Sauce the reading was 499 at 13 degrees C. I did warm these items up as well, and the differences were similar.

For reference I tried distilled water was well and the readings were lower the both the tap water and apple sauce.

So what is the theory behind this? Why are the results this way? I thought water would be the highest, but that wasn't the case.

Thanks in advance.

Dave.

Edit: Chirp! Sensor is a capactive sensor http://wemakethings.net/chirp/

Comment: Fruits are slightly acidic.

Comment: What is a Chirp! sensor?

Comment: @MattYoung: It has to be some sort of conductivity sensor.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Probably, but it's not our job to figure that out.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added an edit about what the Chrip! sensor is. Also, I had a similar higher reading with Milk. It was basically the same as Apple Sauce.

Comment: Find the schematic and provide a link to it unless you expect 30 keen engineers to go wasting their collective time simultaneously.

Comment: Try distilled water vs. salt water in various concentrations. I think @Ignacio is on the right track- it has to do with ionic conductivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chirp! is a capacitance sensor, *not* a dielectric measurement. The designer/author of the writeup seems to have made a slight error when they spoke of the water in the soil changing the dielectric. Rather, the sensor appears to have its own dielectric coating, using the soil/water/applesauce/milk as the second "plate" of the capacitor. As such, generally speaking, electrolytes with a higher dissolved ion concentration should register a higher capacitance, due to the "double layer effect" created by the ions (similar to that used in modern EDL supercaps).
This would explain why milk/applesauce (high ion concentration) had higher readings than tap water (low ion concentration), distilled water (very low ion concentration), or air (extremely sparce in both matter & ions)

EDIT: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_double-layer_capacitor for more info on ionic double-layers & effect on capatance.

Comment: Thanks very much for everyone's help. I think I'm starting to understand it a little better. I think part of my issue is that I thought two different sensors were working the same way, but now I believe they aren't, or at least they have differences. On the one hand there is the Chirp! and on the other hand there is: http://zerocharactersleft.blogspot.ca/2011/11/pcb-as-capacitive-soil-moisture-sensor.html I may pose a new question to better understand the differences. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure how the CHIRP! sensor is constructed, but my answer was based on a (possibly incorrect) assumption that they were using the parallel-plate topology. If, instead they are using coplanar plates, like the other sensor you linked, then my answer was incorrect. Unfortunately, I didn't see anything on the CHIRP! sensor page that specified the capacitance sensor's specific layout/format, so we can only make "educated guesses" based on the information at hand.

Comment: Yes, I realized after that what you said wasn't exactly right, but the information about the electrolytes and ion concentration did make sense and was really what I was looking for in an answer, so overall it answered my question! Thanks.